# Run Python3.4 and Python3.7 simultaneously on Linux

Tags: linux, python, python3

I have a linux VM with preconfigured Python3.4. I need to have Python3.7 to run my code.

I tried to uninstall Python3.4 but there are some system dependencies, so I kept old version.
Then I downloaded and installed Python3.7.1.tgz (sudo make).

But now I can't access Python 3.7 instance. When I run a "python3" command, Python 3.4 is run, when "python3.7" then I get a "command not found" message.

How do I proceed? Is it okay to have two versions of Python 3 installed on one machine? What with installation packages by "pip"?

Comment: Have you installed it properly? Just go through this link once https://serverfault.com/q/918335

Comment: @P_Yadav, thank you for the link. It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend manually fiddling around with source code installations and paths. [Use `pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and save yourself the trouble.

All you have to do is:

- Run the [`pyenv` installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer)
- Follow the instructions
- Install the Python versions you need
- Choose which Python version you want to use for a given directory, or globally

For example, to install 3.7, check which versions are available:

```
pyenv install -l | grep 3.7
```

Then run:

```
pyenv install 3.7.1
```

Now, you can choose your Python version:

```
pyenv global 3.7.1
```

This switches your `python` to point to 3.7.1. If you want the system python, run:

```
pyenv global system
```

To check which Python versions are available, run `pyenv versions`.